# Node.js - How to hide html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, public

I have html pages which shouldn’t be seen by the users who haven’t logged in. I used the command below and my html pages became public.

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

For example, I do not want users who are not logged in to see this page.

http://localhost:3000/admin.html

NOTE: what I'm talking about is not a cookie. When you enter the address of the html page in the toolbar, if it is not logged in, it should not be able to reach that page.

Comment: You'll need some sort of conditional like `app.get('/protected', (req, res) => { if (req.user) { ... `

Comment: But if the user writes by hand, can't he still see it? example www.example.com/protected.html .  Because it's not going to /protected, it's going to /protected .html

Comment: It sounds like we're just talking about authorization here.  You could do it by running Node behind apache auth, nginx, or by using express middleware like passport.

Comment: I think the problem is not authorization. Because /user and /user.html are not the same. The user can type the name of the html page in the toolbar and get there again. Because the server is controlling /user, not /user.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `static` middleware, with the middleware you can validate the path(filename for this case).

I will try to explain with comments in a example code:

```
// path.join here makes it work cross platform with Windows / Linux / etc
var statics = express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));


function secureStatic(pathsToSecure = []) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (pathsToSecure.length === 0) {
      return statics(req, res, next); // Do not secure, forward to static route
    }

    if (pathsToSecure.indexOf(req.path) > -1) {
      return res.status(403).send('<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>'); // Stop request
    }

    return statics(req, res, next); // forward to static route
  };
}


// add public files. List all "private" paths (file)
app.use(secureStatic(['admin.html'])); // instead of app.use(express.static('public'));
```

But, with this middleware, no one can request to `admin.html` file via you express server.